# How do I get the function in my object to display its return value?

Tags: javascript

whenever I try to print my function to the console I get the following output:

```
  { Subject: 'fiction',
  Author: 'John Wayne',
  PublicationDate: 1890-02-18T07:33:52.000Z,
  DaysSincePublished: [Function] }
```

The value of DaysSincePublished property is supposed to display the number of days that have passed since the date of the publication of the book and the present day. Instead it displays the type of the value for said property.

```
function Book(Subject, Author, PublicationDate) { 

  const book = {
    Subject:Subject,
    Author:Author,
    PublicationDate:PublicationDate,
    DaysSincePublished: function() {
  const Interval = Math.round(((new Date) - this.PublicationDate) / (1000*60*60*24));
  return Interval;
    }
  }

  return book;

}

var book1 = new Book("fiction", "John Wayne", new Date("18 February 1890"));
console.log(book1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the object `book` has a function at the property `DaysSincePublished`, is not a value. Instead of doing the calculus and assigning it to the property, do it outside and pass the resulting the value to the property (more elegant and readable than doing everything together in the same line).

Also take care with the `this` keyword, which seems to be non-sense in this context.

```
function Book(Subject, Author, PublicationDate) { 

  function calculateDays() {
    const Interval = Math.round((new Date() - PublicationDate) / (1000*60*60*24));
    return Interval;
  }

  const book = {
    Subject:Subject,
    Author:Author,
    PublicationDate:PublicationDate,
    DaysSincePublished: calculateDays()
  }

  return book;

}
```

The difference here is that you're not assigning a function to the property, instead you are assigning the evaluation (result) of that function!

---

Some off-topic comments:

As a suggestion, use [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) in variable names, as using Capitalized names tends to be for Classes (like `Date` or `Math`). I'm not saying that your code won't work, but as a convention, it's recommended to use it to avoid confusions! So e.g. try to write `publicationDate` instead of `PublicationDate`.

Here is a more good-looking code that does the same:

```
function book(subject, author, publicationDate) { 

  function calculateDays() {
    return Math.round((new Date() - publicationDate) / (1000*60*60*24));
  }

  return {
    subject: subject,
    author: author,
    publicationDate: publicationDate,
    daysSincePublished: calculateDays()
  }
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect, as this.PublicationDate is undefined

Answer (score 0):

remove "this" as this is book object, which does not have PublicationDate before its constructed. Also run function to get value

```
function Book(Subject, Author, PublicationDate) { 

  const book = {
    Subject:Subject,
    Author:Author,
    PublicationDate:PublicationDate,
    DaysSincePublished: (function() {
  const Interval = Math.round(((new Date) - PublicationDate) / (1000*60*60*24));
  return Interval;
    })()
  }

  return book;

}

var book1 = new Book("fiction", "John Wayne", new Date("18 February 1890"));
console.log(book1);
```

Comment: This solved it, thanks. Question: why will the numerical value for DaysSincePublished only display if you put the extra brackets? I'm talking about the brackets that you put around the function and the empty brackets afterwards.

Comment: What you are doing is to encapsulate the function and run it. Instead of defining a function `f`, you are assigning the value of executing the function with `f()`

Answer (score 0):

sort of copy from **Shishir Arora**

```js
function Book(Subject, Author, PublicationDate) { 
  const book = {
    Subject           : Subject,
    Author            : Author,
    PublicationDate   : PublicationDate,
    DaysSincePublished: (()=> Math.round(((new Date) - PublicationDate) / (1000*60*60*24)))()
  }
  return book;
}

var book1 = new Book("fiction", "John Wayne", new Date("18 February 1890"));
console.log(book1);
```